# Save SVG(contains animations) as PNG file without canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, image, animation, svg

How to download svg as PNG file ? SVG may contain animations, so i don't want to use canvas, with below code i am able to download image in svg format, any suggestions please for converting svg to png in javascript?

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http:​/​/​www.w3.org/​2000/​svg" width="993" height="550">............'; 
a.download = 'image.svg';
a.click();
```

Comment: So you want to generate an APNG from a SMIL/CSS animated SVG, without the use of the canvas ? Not an easy task ;-) It would need an homemade svg parser + renderer supporting SMIL or CSS animations, an homemade APNG encoder/LZIP compressor. Could be done, theoretically...

Comment: Can i do at server side in java? my svg contains foreign object, which contains image and html code

Comment: So let's make it clear : - how do you want to deal with your animated SVGs ? Do you want an APNG, a gif, or a succession of pngs ? If you were thinking of Batik, they do support SMIL, but they don't support HTML in svg, the only user agents I know that do support both are web browsers. For animated svg + HTML, give canvg library a try, they are able to rasterize some svg animations on the canvas.

Comment: I want an APNG, yeah i tried batik it did not worked, i will try canvg library

Answer (score -2):

You can use Inkscape to convert the svg image to png it can be installed on a Linux and Windows machine but I would recommend Linux for more details refer https://inkscape.org/en/

Comment: Does Inkscape support exporting animated SVGs to APNG ? [I guess they don't...](https://inkscape.org/en/learn/animation/)

Comment: you need to convert to gif, apng are not supported. you can also use http://www.imagemagick.org/ or ghostscript for this.

Comment: But I doubt that even animated gif conversion is supported since the f.a.q I linked to states that inkscape doesn't natively support animation in svg.

Comment: you can also use imagemagick.org by this command
 convert -delay 5 -loop 0 frame??.svg animated.gif

Comment: but even imagemagick doesn't support animated svg. + OP clarified that he wanted it done by js.

Comment: He also didn’t want to convert it to APNG he just asked for PNG.